# How to send Petitions Multi Thread Python / Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django and I need to send many requests, there is any way to send it on multi-thread? This is my code.

```py
def send_ws_info(serializer, id):
    url = f'{settings.WS_URL}/notify/{id}'
    token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user__id=id)
    headers = {'Authorization': f'Token {token.key}'}
    requests.post(url=url, json=serializer, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a threadpoolexecutor

```py
import requests
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

ids = [
1,
2,
3,
]

def send_ws_info(serializer, id):
    url = f'{settings.WS_URL}/notify/{id}'
    token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user__id=id)
    headers = {'Authorization': f'Token {token.key}'}
    requests.post(url=url, json=serializer, headers=headers)


processes = []
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    for id in ids :
        processes.append(executor.submit(send_ws_info, serializer, id))

for task in as_completed(processes):
    print(task.result())
```